# how to combine years in group to 10 in a sqlite query

Tags: python, sql, pandas, sqlite, date

MOVIE (Mid, name, year, rank)
i want to count the number of movies in a decade. Suppose year in the table start from 1931
then years from 1931 to 1940  will form a decade.

My Query:

```
query_7 = pd.read_sql_query('''SELECT yr.year as dec_start,yr.year + 9 as dec_end,COUNT(DISTINCT m.MID) as num_movies
                             FROM  (SELECT DISTINCT year FROM Movie) yr ,Movie m WHERE m.year >= yr.year
                             AND m.year < yr.year + 10
                             GROUP BY yr.year 
                             ORDER BY yr.year 
                             ''',conn)
```

Output:

[image]

Problem with this query is for each unique year it start counting decade from that.
whereas required output is if 1931 is the lowest year in the database then first decade should start from 1931 and next from 1941 not from 1936.

any insight on this is much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want decades starting with the minimum year in the table use this:

```
SELECT 
  (year - s.start_from) / 10 * 10 + s.start_from as dec_start, 
  (year - s.start_from) / 10 * 10 + s.start_from + 9 as dec_end,
  COUNT(DISTINCT MID) as num_movies
FROM  Movie CROSS JOIN (SELECT MIN(year) % 10 start_from FROM Movie) s
GROUP BY dec_start, dec_end
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qb3MqMJR8c5761XTjVmJLv/5).

Comment: @LalitJain I have corrected and simplified the code.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this does what you want:

```
SELECT 
    year/10 * 10 + 1 as dec_start,
    year/10 * 10 + 10 as dec_end,
    COUNT(mid) as num_movies
FROM  Movie
GROUP BY year/10 
ORDER BY dec_start
```

This works by performing integer division on the year, and then adjusting to get the decade.

Say year is `1934`, `year/10` is `193`, then `193 * 10 + 1` produces `1931`, while `193 * 10 + 10` yields `1940`.

I don't think that you actually need `count(distinct)` (`count()` should do it).

Comment: Could please help me understand why my original query is giving result for each unique year

Comment: @LalitJain: the main problem with your original query is that it is grouping by year, while you need to group by decade (so `year/10`)

Comment: year/10 will give 3 digit number if the decade is starting from 1941 then year/10 will be 194 so while grouping it will check if year has 194 and based on this it group all movies. right??

Comment: @LalitJain: yes indeed.

Comment: @GBM but then this query is only valid if decade is starting from 1931 or say from one's digit is 1. if year start from 1935 then it won't work?

Comment: @LalitJain: see the example that I gave in my answer. If year is 1935, the computation returns 1931 as start decade and 1940 as end of decade.

Comment: @GBM but my requirement is if first year is 1935 then decade will be 1935,1936.........1944  not  1931 to 1940.